# How do I pass the event handler to a custom trigger handler

Tags: javascript, triggers, event-handling, jquery

I would like to know how I can pass the event handler from the `keydown` and `keyup` event (`e`), to the custom trigger handler (`start` and `stop`). I need this in order for the functions moveWorldStart and moveWorldStop to be able to get its value.

```
$(window).keydown(function(e){
    $(document).trigger('start');
}).keyup(function(e){
    $(document).trigger('stop');
});

$(document).on('start', moveWorldStart);
$(document).on('stop', moveWorldStop);

function moveWorldStart(e) {
    //e.which || e.keyCode == ?
}
function moveWorldStop(e) {
    //e.which || e.keyCode == ?
}
```

I tried putting `e` in [different places](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), but to be frank, I haven't got a clue what I am doing. Can any one nudge me in the right direction? Tyvm :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
$(window).keydown(function(e){
    $(document).trigger({
        type:"start",
        userEvent:e     
    });
});

function moveWorldStart(e) {
    console.log(e.userEvent)
}
```

Have a look at JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qyL56/

Have a look at documentation: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/